# A good form dockin component is needed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dock

I use a free dockcontainer control in my projects. 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/VS_IDE_Dock_Container.aspx
After a while I realized it has several bugs, so I should switch to a new one.

Would you be so kind to recommend me a dock container system (like VS 2010 UI)? Does anyone know a **really good, stable free** component or an opensource project?

(WinForms/VS2010/C#/.Net 4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the library is a little aged I was very happy with [WeifenLuo DockPanel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/). It is well documented and really easy to use. Not so intrusive in your code - even if you have to derive from a class to became a dockable panel, you can stick your existing user controls upon a panel you will create. In plus it is reliable: I had a GUI with this in prod and  I never had problem about docking even in a day by day usage.

Comment: Seems OK for me. Only thing I can not handle when loading from XML: "DockPanel has already been initialized...". It seems to be a common problem, could not find any solution in its forums.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to remember since I've not the source here. When you deserialize back the objects you don't have to add mannually teh panels into the dock.

Comment: Very kind from you to help me. So, it happens when there is some item (document) on the dockpanel and I try to load a saved view from XML. I should close the existing ones programatically before loading from XML. If I do it- works. Thanks very much for your help! This component is added to my project and so far so good. Hope, will be better than my old one ;)

Comment: @Tom, if you still have problems, I suggest to you to open a new question with the offending code.

Answer (score 1):

A perfect solution for this would be [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/), were it not that it's written in WPF. You can use WindowsFormsHost controls to overcome this if your requirement is using Windows Forms.

Comment: App is completely written in WinForms and 90% of the UI is completed, so I can not switch to WPF.

Comment: You can use WindowsFormsHost to host your WinForms user controls in WPF